# $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with finite index. Prove that G has finitely many subgroups of form $xHx^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with finite index. Prove tat $G$ has finitely many subgroups of form $xHx^{-1}$.

Let $h\in H$, $x\in G$

Since H is a subgroup of G

$h \in G$

$\rightarrow he \in G$ (Identity element is also found in G due to subgroup property.)

=$ h(xx^{-1}) \in G $

=$xhx^{-1} \in G$ (Associative property due to subgroup property)

Hence proved.

I need to know if this is Proof is complete and whether it contains errors.

Comment: The proof does not prove what you are asked to prove (you seem to be proving that conjugating something in $H$ by something gives something in $G$ which is clear since $G$ is a group).

Comment: $G$ could be an infinite group. So you have to prove that we cannot find infinitely many distinct subgroups of the type $xHx^{-1}$. You have not done that yet.

Comment: I think you have mistaken associativity and commutativity as well.

Comment: @Sirus Black Notice that what you have tried to show is that $xhx^{-1}$ is in $G$ which is always true for any group. What you have to prove requires "$H$ has finite index in $G$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the number of different conjugates of $H$ equals the index $|G:N_G(H)|$ of its normalizer, and $H$ is contained in this subgroup.